# Inserting Cell Value Performance

Tags: vba

My code looks at a table with three different Ids and a qty. It sums all rows where the three ids are the same and pastes it sheet2. The original table is always sorted with the three Id columns sorted in alphabetical order.

```
Original Table
+--------+------+---------+-----+
|  Name  | City | Country | Qty |
+--------+------+---------+-----+
| Jack   | A    | US      |  15 |
| Jack   | A    | US      |  16 |
| Kevin  | A    | US      |  12 |
| Kevin  | A    | US      |  11 |
| Jack   | B    | US      |  13 |
| Jack   | B    | US      |  10 |
+--------+------+---------+-----+

Output Table
+--------+------+---------+-----+
|  Name  | City | Country | Qty |
+--------+------+---------+-----+
| Jack   | A    | US      |  31 |
| Kevin  | A    | US      |  23 |
| Jack   | B    | US      |  23 |
+--------+------+---------+-----+

Code

For i = 2 To totalrow  'totalrow is the total number of rows

name = sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
city = sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
country = sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
qty = 0

Do
    qty = qty + sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
    i = i + 1
Loop While wsDB.Cells(i, 1) = name And wsDB.Cells(i, 2) = city And wsDB.Cells(i, 3) = country

    sheet2.Cells(process_row, 1).Value = name
    sheet2.Cells(process_row, 2).Value = city
    sheet2.Cells(process_row, 3).Value = country
    sheet2.Cells(process_row, 4).Value = qty
    process_row = process_row + 1
    i = i - 1
Next I
```

I timed how long the code took to run and it consistently takes 30 seconds.
I then removed the section pasting the updated values into sheet2 and timed it (code below). That consistently took less than 1 second.

```
For i = 2 To totalrow

bl = wsDB.Cells(i, 1)
cpty = wsDB.Cells(i, 2)
cptyname = wsDB.Cells(i, 3)
cusip = wsDB.Cells(i, 4)
qty = 0

Do
    qty = qty + wsDB.Cells(i, 6)
    i = i + 1
Loop While wsDB.Cells(i, 1) = bl And wsDB.Cells(i, 2) = cpty And wsDB.Cells(i, 4) = cusip

    process_row = process_row + 1
    i = i - 1
Next i
```

It appears that inserting cell values requires the most time. Are there any methods in which I can speed this up?

Comment: You can set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (remembering to toggle back on at the end of the Sub_. You may also have formulas referencing these cells, meaning every time any of them change, it recalculates. You can set `application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start of the code, and toggle it back to `application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end of the code so it only calculates once.

Comment: The fastest method to work with the cells is `For Each` rather than `For i` or `Do`. Another way is to fill up an array with the data and paste it to the sheet. With large amounts of data arrays are the way to go always.

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?